# Detect external resources and file sizes used by a given page

Tags: javascript, html, profiling

Using JavaScript, I'm wanting to detect how many JavaScript, CSS and Images are being used by the site. On top of that I'm wanting to get the file size for each asset. Is this possible and if so how would you do this?

Comment: Sadly I don't think in-the-page JS is going to give you what you need. The HTML5 Filesystem API may help, (there're functions for retrieving file info - http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/ '5.1 The Metadata interface') but I think you're in for a very convoluted process to achieve it if is possible.

Answer (score 0):

As to detecting number of external javascripts, css and images used on website it's doable by getting all the script, image and style tags and then checking if they're *external* by comparing document domain to asset domain.

As to checking external resources size with javascript, that could be hard. Even though you could try for example refetch the script and css files using ajax, to get contents of the file (to estimate its size), there would be problems with estimating image size. I guess html5 file api or canvas may be used to get some idea of how large is the image.